# How to rearrange cosines to get angles

Tags: trigonometry

Given this equation:

$$  Z = \frac{10}{\cos a} + \frac{10}{\cos(90-a)}$$

how would I go about rearranging it to get a in terms of Z?

Comment: Try applying the difference formula to cos(90 - a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

As $\cos(90-a)=\sin a$

$$Z=\frac{10}{\cos a}+\frac{10}{\sin a}=\frac{10(\cos a+\sin a)}{\cos a\sin a}$$

Squaring we get, $$Z^2\cdot\frac{\sin^22a}4=100(1+\sin2a)$$ as $\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x$

which on rearrangement, is a Quadratic Equation in $\sin2a$

As we have squared, we  may have introduced [extraneous root(s)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions) which need(s) to be purged, so we need validate the values of $a$

Comment: i am way out of my depth

Comment: @user576496, please pinpoint where you have difficulty in understanding?